# How show in Dired+ count of selected files and size?

Tags: dired

Windows 10, Emacs 25.1, Dired+ (20170818.1411)

In Total commander when I select any files it show count of selected files and total size of selected files.

Here example:

[image: total]
It's very helpful.

But in Emacs in dired mode I can't get this information. 
Here example:

[image: dired]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dired+ does not show the total size of the marked files.

If you show details (as in your screenshot) it does show the number of files shown in each inserted subdir and the total number of files shown in the buffer. And it shows you the space used by each subdir and the main dir, as well as the available space remaining.

And it does show how many files are marked, and how many are flagged for deletion.

You seem to show a [Dired+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus) screenshot, but either it is from a very old Dired+ version or something else (yas? Helm?) must be interfering.

Please try the latest [`dired.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/dired%2b.el).  (Do not get any of my libraries from MELPA. They stopped updating them from Emacs Wiki, where I upload the latest versions.)

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I update dired.el. But the problem is it not show size of selected files. It will be  very helpful.

Comment: Yes, I acknowledged that it does not show the total size of the marked files.